# invalid syntax (<unknown>, line 89) - pylint(syntax-error)

Tags: python, blockchain

Getting a syntax error on this dictionary initialization and I can't figure out why.

```
elif user_choice == "H" or user_choice == "h":
    if len(blockchain) >= 1:
        blockchain[0] = {"previous_hash": "", "index": 0, "transactions": [{"sender": "Chris", "recipient": "Max", "amount", 100.0}]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your list, `amount` has a comma instead of a semicolon:

`[{"sender": "Chris", "recipient": "Max", "amount", 100.0}]`

Should be:

`[{"sender": "Chris", "recipient": "Max", "amount": 100.0}]`